# SignalR not doing anything at all. Nothing is being sent to client when clicking submit

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, razor, signalr

I'm trying to make a simple chatting function for my web application. But it's not working at all, when i try to type in the values in the textbox, and click submit, nothing is being sent to the other client. I tried help from this site:

http://www.ziaahmedshaikh.com/signalr-create-simple-chat-application/

And then implemented it into my own code.

Here is the code for the hub  MyHub.cs:

```
namespace myWebApp.Hubs
{
    public class MyHub : Hub
    {
        public async Task SendMessage(string user, string message)
        {
            await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, message);
        }
    }
}
```

here is MyHub.js

```
"use strict";

var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/MyHub").build();

//Disable send button until connection is established
document.getElementById("sendButton").disabled = true;

connection.on("ReceiveMessage", function (user, message, time) {
    var msg = message.replace(/&/g, "&amp;").replace(g, "&gt;");
    var encodedMsg = " [ " + time + "] " + user + ": " + msg  ;
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.textContent = encodedMsg;
    document.getElementById("messagesList").appendChild(li);
});

connection.start().then(function () {
    document.getElementById("sendButton").disabled = false;
}).catch(function (err) {
    return console.error(err.toString());
});

document.getElementById("sendButton").addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    var user = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
    var message = document.getElementById("messageInput").value;
    connection.invoke("SendMessage", user, message).catch(function (err) {
        return console.error(err.toString());
    });
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

and here is index.cshtml

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-2">User</div>
        <div class="col-4"><input type="text" id="userInput" /></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-2">Message</div>
        <div class="col-4"><input type="text" id="messageInput" /></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
            <input type="button" id="sendButton" value="Send Message" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <hr />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <ul id="messagesList"></ul>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="~/js/signalr.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/MyHub.js"></script>
```

Comment: "In order for a question to be answered, it must specify what exactly is wrong. Stating simply that “it doesn’t work” is not sufficient." See more at http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/

Comment: Alright i edited my question, thanks

Comment: Remove "time" from the client `connection.on("ReceiveMessage",...)`

Comment: Nope still not sending anything